# Error message: too many }'s

Tags: errors, compiling

I have a LaTeX document which works fine but whenever I try to add in an image with a figure caption it gives me an error saying there are to many `}`'s.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{A picture of a gull.}

  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{uml-usecase/overview.png}
\end{figure}
```

My current packages are:

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{newlfont}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xthesis}
\usepackage{xtocinc} %Include Table of Contents as the first entry in TOC
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
```

As far as I can see it's right, can anyone figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: None of the fragments shown here causes this. Its a simple syntax error like `{}}`. What about a minimal example of a complete document shows the error?

Comment: Migrate to tex.se?

Comment: @Phonon: No, don't migrate old questions. Even less if they are already solved.

Comment: +1 for asking the question. It really help me in figuring out the error in my thesis writing.

Comment: +1, Thanks for asking this question, that addressed exactly the problem I had. I don't understand why this question is "too localized" and "unlikely to help any future visitors".

Comment: In my case it was a typo and caused by a simple syntax error like {}}.

Comment: I had this error due to single dangling `}` in my source code

Answer (score 5):

Most probably it is the package `xthesis` that contains some pieces of code to redefine `\@xfloat` in a bad way. It seems that many university's thesis templates contain such a definition from a file named `doublespace.sty`. The solution is to (re)define `\@xfloat` in a "good" way, for example: [a work around here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=4766&start=10#p33170)

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem was the `rotation` package. When removed, the figure caption to works.

Comment: Because `rotation` loads `graphicx` if not loaded yet. You can also put `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` before `\usepackage{rotation}`. But what has this to do with "too many }'s"???

Comment: It could be a LaTeX bug. I see no reason for a downvote.